# Handle all errors from global handling exception in Web API Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I implement global exception handling in Web API Core 3.1 so that I can handle only the 500 error, but I need to handle all errors like 500, 401, 404, 402. How can I achieve this?

```
public static class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    public static void ConfigurationExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(
            appErr =>
            {
                appErr.Run(
                    async context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                        var contexFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                        if (contexFeature != null)
                        {
                           
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync(new ApiResponse{
                                StatusCode=context.Response.StatusCode,
                                Description="Internal server message"
                            }.ToString());
                        }
                    });
            }
      );
    }
}
```

and in startup file:

```
app.ConfigurationExceptionHandler();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo:

1.ExceptionMiddleware:

```
public static class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    public static void ConfigurationExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
        app.UseExceptionHandler(
            appErr =>
            {
                appErr.Run(
                    async context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                        var contexFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                        if (contexFeature != null)
                        {
                            var data = new ApiResponse(context.Response.StatusCode, null);
                            var response = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync(response);
                        }
                        
                    });
            }
      );          
    }
}
```

2.ErrorController:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("{code}")]
    public IActionResult InternalError(int code)
    {
        return new ObjectResult(new ApiResponse(code));
    }
}
```

3.ApiResponse:

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ApiResponse(int statusCode, string description = null)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Description = description ?? GetDefaultMessageForStatusCode(statusCode);
    }

    private static string GetDefaultMessageForStatusCode(int statusCode)
    {
        switch (statusCode)
        {

            case 404:
                return "Resource not found";
            case 500:
                return "Internal server message";
            case 401:
                return "UnAuthorized!";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

4.Test:

```
// [ApiController]   //be sure remove this for asp.net core 3.1
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        //throw new Exception("sad");  //500
        //return Unauthorized();   //401
        return NotFound();         //404
    }
}
```